# How does React implement hooks so that they rely on call order

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

the React Hooks *useState* can attach local state to stateless functional component, for instance

```
const [name, setName] = useState('tom')
const [age, setAge] = useState(25)
```

I am wondering how the local state object tree looks like after executing the two line above? 
[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) says something about how state is handled

> React relies on the order in which Hooks are called

Or the local state is not object tree at all, just an array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hooks internally are implemented as a queue with each hook being represented by a node having the reference to the next one.

From the documentation:

> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each
>   component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data.
>   When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or
>   initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to
>   the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get
>   independent local state.

The architecture would be similar to

```
{
  memoizedState: 'A',
  next: {
    memoizedState: 'B',
    next: {
      memoizedState: 'C',
      next: null
    }
  }
}
```

The schema of a single hook is as  below. It can be found in the [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L243)

```
function createHook(): Hook {
  return {
    memoizedState: null,

    baseState: null,
    queue: null,
    baseUpdate: null,

    next: null,
  };
}
```

The key properties that let hooks behave the way they are are `memoizedState` and `next`.

Before each and every function Component invocation, `prepareHooks()` is gonna be called, where the current fiber and its first hook node in the hooks queue are gonna be stored in global variables. This way, any time we call a hook function `(useXXX())` it would know in which context to run.

After the update `finishHooks(`) will be called, where a reference for the first node in the hooks queue will be stored on the rendered fiber in the `memoizedState` property

Comment: It there a reason why hooks do not allow a name parameter to be passed to solve this problem? e.g. `useState("tom", "state_1")` and fall back to order when the second argument is missing? There might be even the constraint that all hooks should be called on the first render or a reasonable behaviour for late calls?

Or is it meant to enforce that all hooks be called at every render? (in the sense that hook-names could solve the ordering problem but it is necessary that all hooks are called at every render)