# Changing state of generic functional child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components

in my application I use generic Tabs functional component:

```
export default function Tabs() {
    const [currentTabIndex, setCurrentTabIndex] = useState(0);

    [...]
}
```

Now in my `BookingPage` I need to change the `currentTabIndex` of this `Tabs` component,
depending on Redux Store:

```
export default function BookingPage()
    const userCreatedBooking = useSelector([...]); // whenever this value change, I want
                                                   // to invoke Tabs.setCurrentIndex 

    return (
     <>
         <Tabs tabs=[SubPage1, SubPage2]/>
     <>
```

What's a clean way to achieve above? Thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way is to [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) your component to redux and the redux value will be in the props of the component.

If you want to use setCurrentTabIndex every time a value in redux is changed you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

An example of useEffect is in the answer of this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865764/react-usestate-does-not-reload-state-from-props)

**Edit**

I can give you an exemple.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Tabs(props) {
    const [currentTabIndex, setCurrentTabIndex] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
      setCurrentTabIndex(props.value)
    }, [props.value]); // Will only run if props.value change
    [...]
}
```

```js
export default function BookingPage() {
    const userCreatedBooking = useSelector([...]);

    return (
     <>
         <Tabs 
         value={userCreatedBooking} // or any value in your redux
         tabs=[SubPage1, SubPage2]
         />
     <>
     )
}
```

More information on [useEffect](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/) and how to connect your component to [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect)

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on this solution? I still don't see, how would I invoke `Tabs.setCurrentIndex ` from the `BookingPage` component.

Comment: I give you an example in the answer

Comment: docmurloc, your answer works great – but perhaps I have not emphasized enough that this is a generic component which I cannot modify (plenty of other people in the company use it). Is there a way to achieve what you have suggested without changing the code within `Tabs` component?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this without changing something in the Tabs component. The child component needs to be aware of a change to have a side effect. You can only use props, hooks or reference in your child component by changing your code in Tabs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation:) I'm marking your answer as accepted.