# React Hooks - What is the recommended way to initialize state variables with useState() from props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm asking if there is (and if yes, what is) the recommended way to initialize state variables in React hooks with a value from the `props`.

So I assume I have a component like this:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
    return (
        ....
    );
}
```

I can use `useState` to create a variable for this component, like this:

```
const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState('someValue');
```

So far so good.
My question is now, if I want to initialize the variable with a value from props, is it recommended to to it directly like this:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState(props.someValue);
}
```

or is it better to initialize it with `null` and then use `useEffect()` to set the value on load:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSomeVariable(props.someValue);
    },[])
}
```

Maybe there are more ways, too. I was just wondering if there is a recommendation here or if in the end it doesn't matter which way you use.

Comment: How often does the sameValue change?

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the comment. That should be consired as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the first approach. This is the standard, idiomatic React way.

```js
function SomeComponent(props) {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState(props.someValue);
}
```

The `useEffect` approach would also work but you don't have any reason to do it, not to mention the state would be `null` the first time your component renders.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `useState(props.someValue)` instead of setting it in `useEffect` because `useEffect` is executed **after** react completes rendering the component and doing so will trigger a re-render because you are setting a new state. If you set it in `useState` you will be able to avoid that extra re-render.

Edit: Depending on the logic of your component you may have to handle the `null` state in your component in case you do it in `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

If the props do not changes, you do not need to use `useState`.

If it changes, do this:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState(props.someValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSomeVariable(props.someValue);
    },[props.someValue])
}
```

Read this question & answer to understand why you need to do this.

[React.useState does not reload state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865764/react-usestate-does-not-reload-state-from-props)

---

I would do it this way:

```
function SomeComponent({someValue}) {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState(someValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSomeVariable(someValue);
    },[someValue])
}
```