# A variable doesn't update when using the useState() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm doing a social networking project on React.

I wanted to replace one component from class - to functional and use hooks, and a global problem appeared:

When I go to a new user, the page displays the status of the previous one

I use `useState()` hook, debugged everything, but for some reason when a new status component is rendered, it doesn't update

```js
const ProfileStatus = (props) => {
  const [edditMode, setEdditMode] = useState(false);
  const [status, setValue] = useState(props.status || "Empty");

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const activateMode = () => {
    setEdditMode(true);
  };
  const deactivateMode = () => {
    setEdditMode(false);
    props.updateUserStatus(status);
  };
```

I thought the problem was that the container component was still a class component, but by redoing it, nothing has changed.

Comment: Duplicate of [React.useState does not reload state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865764/react-usestate-does-not-reload-state-from-props)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by using the `useEffect` hook to trigger an update when props change. You can use the hook to do comparison between current props and previous props, then update status in the state.

Use this as reference and adapt according to your own code.

```
const ProfileStatus = (props) => {
  const [edditMode, setEdditMode] = useState(false);
  const [status, setValue] = useState(props.status || "Empty");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.status || "Empty");
  }, [props.status]);

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const activateMode = () => {
    setEdditMode(true);
  };
  const deactivateMode = () => {
    setEdditMode(false);
    props.updateUserStatus(status);
  };
```